# What are the safety precautions I should take if I want to experiment with C. elegans (at home)?

Tags: lab-techniques, safety

*Caenorhabditis elegans* (*C. elegans*) is a nematode (roundworm), and many nematodes do infect humans and cause diseases.

How much is *C. elegans* safe (or unsafe) in this respect?

*C.elegans* is a popular model organism, but is it safe to experiment with it at home? Or risk of infection shall outweigh desire and interest for home science?

Comment: *Caenorhabditis elegans* is completely safe, it is a soil worm not parasitics. you can google the name if you don't believe be.